# How to scroll top on a list of items that change in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a scrollable list of items that look like this:

[image]

I can scroll down into this list. But then, if I did scroll down and change the button number on the top to display a different list of items, then the scroll of what I did on the number before stays there instead of going up:

[image]

This behavior is not the expected. I would like to see the list of items of button 4 from the top of the displayed list.

Til now, I tried using `scrollTo` and some customised scrollings based on ids, but with no luck.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an empty div at the top and call `scrollIntoView()`:

```js
function App() {
  const topElement = useRef(null);

  return <>
    <Pagination />
    <ScrolledWrapper>
      <div ref={topElement} />
      <List />
    </ScrolledWrapper>
  </>
}
```

In the pagination handler:

```js
const onChangePage = () => {
  // ...
  topElement.current?.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  })
}
```

Comment: I was trying to apply a solution as the one you provided with no luck. But this one works perfectly! Thanks :-)